# How to convert PDF to read on Android Kindle?

Tags: pdf, kindle-for-android

I can convert my PDFs to the nice AZW format through the Amazon Kindle free email converter.

However, I did not yet figure out how I can add the resulting .azw file to my Android Kindle app as well - does anyone know how to do this?

I've tried copying it to the /kindle directory where the `.mobi` files are, but it does not recognize it

Comment: Any special reason that you want to use Kindle? There are plenty of apps that read PDFs directly on Android, e.g. Adobe's own Reader and Aldiko eBook.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for all ebook conversions.

Comment: Okay, why? This is not a very useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm coming in late here, but there are a couple more suggestions to convert/push documents to the KF:

- Mail it to your [your-kindle]@kindle.com address with 'convert' in the subject line.
- Use the [Send to Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?docId=1000778781) app (Mac version; Windows version link on page) which automates the process with drag-and-drop.
- The [Send to Kindle bookmarklet](http://www.klip.me/sendtokindle/) claims to push web-content to your Kindle (I haven't tried this one).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should make sure the ebook format that the Android Kindle supports first. EPUB is the most common ebook format for ebooks, nearly all ebook readers can recognize this format, including Kindle. So you should convert PDF to EPUB foramt.

1. Download a PDF to EPUB converter. I recommend [PDFMate PDF Converter](http://www.pdfmate.com), which is developed by my company
2. Add the PDF to the program to convert it as EPUB format.
3. Transfer the EPUB format to Kindle.